# How view to model communication happens in MVC

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have been reading about MVC from a book. The confusion is about the fact how the view to model communication happens. I want to understand how this happens in a simple java web application which uses JSP and servlets.

> the view usually gets the state and data it needs to display, directly
>   from the model

It is the controller which changes the state of a model object. Once it is changed, the controller passes that specific object to a JSP page via the request object.

in controller servlet

```
rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/success.jsp");
User userObj = new User(username, password);
request.setAttribute("user", userObj); 
rd.forward(request, response);
```

in success.jsp

```
<%  
User bean=(User)request.getAttribute("user");  
out.print("Welcome, "+bean.getName());  
%>
```

The request dispatcher forwarded the request and response objects to the jsp page. the jsp page used the request object to get access to the modified model object (userObj). is this what is meant by the view talks to the model? is this the fundamental way of communication between the view and the model? (I mean through `request.getAttribute()`?)

Comment: It all depends on which philosophy you follow, for example, some would say that the view and model should never talk directly with each other, but should communicate via the controller

Comment: so both are accepted? in my code does the view and the model talk?

Comment: Either are acceptable, but you should maintain the use of one or the other. But I say that the controller is passing the model directly the view in this case (if we assume the model is the `User`)

Comment: if my view is not talking to the model, then how does the view to model communication happen in real code?

Comment: Based on the disconnected nature of the web, the view MUST talk to the controller in order to communicate changes to the model and visa-versa

Comment: Since MVC is based on the observer pattern, the view can simply observe the model. When changes occur the observer (view) gets notified and can request to be updated or, based on the observer pattern, the observable can pass itself and needed arguments the the observer. The code to do that is rather simple. [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html).

Comment: the view has to subscribe to the model in order to be updated when something changes. how can a jsp do that? any code examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a MVC architecture Controller receives the data from the request object, manipulates the model & then forwards the flow to the jsp. Jsp fetches from the scope in which the attribute is set & displays.

There are several scopes wherein you can set the attribute.

```
Request, Session, ServletContext
```

each scope has `getAttribute()` & `setAttribute()`

```
${requestScope.yourValue} : request scope which is also the default
${sessionScope.yourValue} : retrieving from the session scope
${applicationScope.yourValue} : retrieving from the context scope
```

When the JSP is fetching the value from the respective scopes, this is the example of view talking to the model. Besides it's not a mandate that you stick to this flow, you can always customize the flow of the app as per your requirements.